# Is it possible to know whether a GKPlayer has your game installed?

Tags: iphone, gamekit

I'm using the `GKPlayer` object's `loadPlayersForIdentifiers:withCompletionHandler:` method to get an array of the `GKLocalPlayer`'s friend data.

What I want, is a subset of those friends who have my app installed. Is this possible? I haven't yet tested this method... sort of trying to plot it all out before I go this route.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you check the header or class reference for GKPlayer?

Comment: Obviously, I have already looked there, or I wouldn't be posting here.

Comment: You'd be surprised. Anyway, if it's not there, it's probably just not possible.

Comment: If it's true this is not possible, then how can we present a custom UI for GK turn-based games (without, of course, resorting to writing your own server to keep track of players)? We would be forced to use the "built in" view controller to start all games, which seems unacceptable, IMHO.

Comment: I haven't tried for turn based games, but for regular games (I just checked with Fruit Ninja, which my GF doesn't have), with the game center view, you can invite anybody, doesn't matter if they have the game or not. If what you are asking for was possible and meant to be used, it'd be right there on the class reference, that's the reason for my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I dont think it's possible - you will get some GKPlayer objects. Then you will have access to:

- playerID
- alias
- isFriend

if you would have access to their achievements, you could probably check for a hidden acheivement or something... but I dont think its the case

[GKPlayer class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)